# Powershell -command text not appearing

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.1

Windows 10, Powershell -v 5.1

I have tried to restore powershell to defaults, both normally and as admin. I have changed/turned off high contrast settings, deleted console files for powershell in Regedit, as well as tried to restore defaults from command line scripts.

Have tried restarting after applying all of this, but much of my output text is invisible, as well as commands with only one "-" dash, but commands with "--" appear.

See in pics below

[no - identifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7iU3.png)

[Invisible "-i"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFNUw.png)

[Reappearing "--i"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAilv.png)

[Invisible Surge Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxsi3.png)

Comment: Did you check your profiles? There are several ones… check $pshome/profile.ps1 and $profile first...

Comment: Does issue persist if you change console background color to black? Likely the text is the same color as your background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like **you've persistently modified the console-window colors in a manner that renders certain syntactic elements invisible**.
You can either modify your console-window settings interactively - which may be nontrivial - or you can try to restore the original colors by recreating
the shortcut files that start your console windows:

Shortcut files (`*.lnk` files) contain their own console-window settings, which are independent of the defaults defined for console windows in the `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]` registry key and its subkeys named for specific executable names / window titles.

Therefore, even if you remove `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]` or specific subkeys, starting a program via a shortcut file will still apply the settings stored inside that shortcut file.

To **bypass the shortcut-file settings *ad hoc***, you can start your program *directly*, using the `Run` dialog:
Press <kbd>WinKey+R</kbd> and enter `powershell` (for Windows PowerShell) or `pwsh` (for PowerShell *Core*), which applies only the registry defaults, if any.

However, **to solve that problem *persistently***, you must **modify or recreate the shortcut 
file(s) you use to start your program**:

**To *modify* the shortcut**:

- Invoke your program via the shortcut,
- then open the system menu (click on the icon in the top-left corner of the window),
- select `Properties`
- and modify the properties, notably the colors via the `Colors` tab.

**To *recreate* the shortcut** (instructions based on Windows 10):

- In the Start Menu:

  - Right-click on the application of interest, then select `More > Open file location`.
- In the taskbar:

  - Right-click on the application of interest, then right-click the application name and select `Properties`.
  - Activate the `General` tab
  - Copy the value of the `Location:` field - the folder in which the `*.lnk` file is located - to the clipboard.
  - Open File Explorer and paste the location into its address bar, which should open the folder in which the `*.lnk` file of interest is located.

Once you've located the `*.lnk` file of interest:

- Make a note of:

  - its exact filename (typically: `Windows PowerShell`)
  - its target command line, by right-clicking the file, selecting `Properties`, selecting the `Shortcut` tab and copying the value of the `Target:` field.
  - its startup directory, as noted in the `Start in:` field.
- Delete the `*.lnk` file.
- Recreate it with the previously noted target command line:

  - Right-click in an empty part of the File Explorer window and select `New > Shortcut`
  - Paste the command line and click `Next`.
  - Specify the previous filename, and click on `Finish`.
  - Right-click on the new file, select `Properties`, and paste the startup directory into field `Start in:`, then click OK.
- Drag the new `*.lnk` file into the Start Menu and/or taskbar, as needed.